# Matching / imputing between experimental and control group on a specific (i.e. latent) variable

Tags: experiment-design, causality, matching, treatment-effect

I am currently researching the impact of survey participation on subsequent behavior, i.e., does **merely** participating in an intention survey about fitness products influence post survey spending. As such, I conducted a simple experiment (survey participation yes/no).

I would love to control for prior satisfaction with fitness products, which, unfortunately, cannot be observed. As such my only means of getting this information is to ask survey participants about their prior satisfaction - which I cannot, since this survey itself would influence my main effect.

Is there any way to use / match / impute the prior satisfaction answers of my control group with my treatment (i.e., survey) group?